# reload cell in table with ajax

Tags: php, html, xml, ajax

I want to create a calendar in which I can choose when f.e. my practice is open/closed. This calendar is used as a standard scheme for every week.
e.g. http://www.restaurantterpolder.be/wachtkamer/vast.php

Standard the practice is always closed except when you click on the cell. Then this is written to the database: tbl_open(ID, Weekday, Moment_ID, Doctor_ID).
Because this is a weekly scheme I use 'Weekday' instead of 'Date'.

When altering the bottom cells the page jumps up every time after a reload and that's pretty annoying. So I thought I could use Ajax to reload the cell.

If I'm not mistaken I need:
- event on page which calls the script -> onClick=getInfo(this.id);. This should be called when clicking on a hyperlink.
- js-file which can get content from xml file
- php-file called from the js-file who 1)saves data 2)loads new date 3)creates xml-file

Am i right so far?

I try to start like this:

```
<a onClick="getInfo(this.id);" id="tbl_close_id"><img ... /></a>
```

The Ajax

```
var xmlHttp

//gegevens verzamelen om de juiste info uit de database te kunnen halen
function showInfo(str)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
    if (xmlHttp==null)
{
         alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
return
}

var url="responsexml_calendar.php"
url=url+"?q="+str
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random()
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
}

//info is uit de database gehaald en wordt nu in het formulier geplaatst
function stateChanged() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
{ 
        xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        document.getElementById("class").value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("class")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("link").value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var objXMLHttp=null
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
return objXMLHttp
}
```

The PHP-file where I check if the practice is open or closed that day:

```
//SAVE OR DELETE DATA IN DATABASE FIRST (still need to code this)

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

$query = 'SELECT ID
    FROM tbl_open
    WHERE ID = '.$q.'

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('foutmelding query ajax');

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $class = 'class = "normal"';
    $link = '<a onClick="getInfo(this.id);" id="tbl_close_id"><img ... /></a><img src="./img/edit.png" /></a>'. PHP_EOL;
}
else
{
    $class = 'class="unavailable"';
    $link = '<a onClick="getInfo(this.id);" id="tbl_close_id"><img ... /></a><img src="./img/edit.png" /></a>'. PHP_EOL;
}

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<info>';
    echo "<class>" .$class. "</class>";
    echo "<link>" .$link. "</link>";
echo "</info>";
?>
```

Comment: you are allways right if it works

Answer (score 1):

First I need to say that I recommend to use the jQuery Javascript library.
Everything is much easier and shorter with jQuery:

http://jquery.com/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

An ajax request in jQuery looks like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'responsexml_calendar.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    alert(data.class+' ' + data.link);
  }
});
```

The syntax is a little bit strange, but you will get a return of investment if you learn it.

You don't need the whole GetXmlHttpObject stuff. Everything is managed by jQuery and you don't need to deal with different implementations in different browsers. jQuery is cross-browser compatible.

I have chosen datatype "json" here. Json is simpler than xml. You should use json (less overhead)

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation

A json object looks like this:

```
{'class':'someclass','link':'somelink'}
```

You used:

```
document.getElementById("class").value = "yourvalue";
```

with jQuery it would look like this:

```
$('#class').val("yourvalue");
```

much easier and shorter.